# Package Name change results in permanent permissions problem

Tags: java, android, package

I mistyped the package name when I created my android project, and it took me a while to notice. I used Eclipse's Rename function on the package to change it, and sort out all the references. I've updated the Manifest, and manually checked every file for any references to the old package name. However when I launch the app (it's a live wallpaper) and click settings, I get an IllegalStateException, exactly as if the permissions were not set up correctly (which they are). I've manually uninstalled the app and restarted eclipse. Is there any way out of this?

Update:

This is an android problem, not an eclipse problem. I created a new project in eclipse, and copied everything over, and when I ran it I got the same error.

Further update:

I've managed to get it working, I had to set the Activity to export in the manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to Clean the project like this:

(In the menu) Go to Project -> Clean -> and try to clean your current project.

I had a similiar issue before and this solved it.